# The specified folder could not be found in the store Error

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to retrieve the list of appointment from a specific meeting room using Exchange Web Services managed API.
I'm using Office365 and Exchange Online.
I tried the following code.

```
  try
    {
    ExchangeService newExchangeService = new ExchangeService  (ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
    //Admin permission account
    newExchangeService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    newExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(email-id, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

    SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection();
searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.Start, startDate));
searchFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.IsLessThanOrEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.Start, endDate));
ItemView view = new ItemView(50);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.AppointmentType, AppointmentSchema.End);


var calendarSearch = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox("adachi@fairuse.jp"));
var appointmentresult = service.FindItems(calendarSearch, searchFilter, view);
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
```

I got the error:

> The specified folder could not be found in the store.

Apparently this is a permissions issue, but where is this permission set?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a new mailbox, a string with only the mail address is enough:

```
var calendarSearch = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "adachi@fairuse.jp");
```

As for permissions: Ar you in a domain? Do you use NTLM or ADFS?